# Create a new dictionary from many dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is it possible to create a dictionary from other dictionaries?

I have a list of dictionaries, that look like so:

```
my_dicts = 
[{'1A': 1, '3E': 2, 'PRODUCT NAME': 'White Bread loaf large', 'Week': 1},
 {'1A': 1, '1B': 1, '1C': 1, '1D': 2, '1E': 2, '2C': 1, '3E': 2, 'PRODUCT NAME': 'Brown Bread loaf 
 large', 'Week': 1}...]
```

I want to create a dictionary, that will look like this:

```
new_dict = 
[{'HOUSE NAME': '1A', 'White Bread Loaf Large' : 1, 'Brown Bread loaf large' : 1},
 {'HOUSE NAME': '1B', 'Brown Bread loaf large' : 1},...
 {'HOUSE NAME': '3E', 'White Bread Loaf Large' : 2, 'Brown Bread Loaf Large' : 2}]
```

basically I want the the key 'HOUSE NAME' , with value of every household name, with the 'my_dicts' 'PRODUCT NAME' as the keys, and the value being the house names' values (I.E 1)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Small suggestion, seems like you want to store all the value related to particular `HOUSE_NAME` together, that means it's going to be an unique entry. Why not use it as key to the dictionary? And rest of fields as value in dictionary?

Comment: Yes actually using the HOUSE_NAME as the key to the dictionary is a great idea I will do that, thank you! @Anonymous

Comment: @WBM I haven't actually tried anything yet besides a basic for loop to be honest with you, I am a little lost in what to do, so anything would be a great help

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66055891/5237560  (same question, same poster)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a new dictionary from a list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66043828/creating-a-new-dictionary-from-a-list-of-dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean ,but I suggest you use a list inside the House_Name values to save the PRODUCT NAME values in string format

Answer (score 0):

my answer just requires one prerequisite that's you having a set/unique list of house `IDs`

```py
my_dicts = [{
    '1A': 1,
    '3E': 2,
    'PRODUCT NAME': 'White Bread loaf large',
    'Week': 1
}, {
    '1A': 1,
    '1C': 2,
    'PRODUCT NAME': 'White Bread loaf large',
    'Week': 1
}, {
    '1A': 1,
    '1B': 1,
    '1C': 1,
    '1D': 2,
    'PRODUCT NAME': 'Brown Bread loaf large',
    'Week': 1
}]

# !:Prerequisite you have the IDs as a unique set
houses = set(['1A', '1B', '1C', '1D', '3E'])

output_list = []

for house in houses:
    output_entry = {}
    output_entry["HOUSE NAME"] = house
    for entry in my_dicts:
        if entry.get(house) and entry.get("PRODUCT NAME"):
            product_name = entry.get("PRODUCT NAME")
            if output_entry.get(product_name):
                output_entry[product_name] += 1
            else:
                output_entry[product_name] = 1

    output_list.append(output_entry)

print(output_list)
```

You can make this even more concise with `map` and `filter`

**Output:**

```py
[
    {'HOUSE NAME': '1A', 'White Bread loaf large': 2, 'Brown Bread loaf large': 1}, 
    {'HOUSE NAME': '1C', 'White Bread loaf large': 1, 'Brown Bread loaf large': 1}, 
    {'HOUSE NAME': '1B', 'Brown Bread loaf large': 1}, 
    {'HOUSE NAME': '3E', 'White Bread loaf large': 1}, 
    {'HOUSE NAME': '1D', 'Brown Bread loaf large': 1}
]
```

> ***This is just to show how `map` and `filter` works on request of the *OP*, Please don't do this as it makes code less readable and not pythonic***

```py
from functools import reduce
...
output_entry["HOUSE NAME"] = house
    output_entry = {
        **output_entry,
        **dict(
            reduce(
                lambda x, y: {
                    k: x.get(k, 0) + y.get(k, 0)
                    for k in set(x) | set(y)
                }, (map(
                    lambda x: {x["PRODUCT NAME"]: 1},
                    filter(lambda x: x.get(house) and x.get("PRODUCT NAME"), my_dicts)))))
    }

    output_list.append(output_entry)

print(output_list)
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain how the map and filter would work sorry?

Comment: @Luca added a code snippet. **Please don't use the last bit of code**. I did it because Python allows it, it's not best practice.

Comment: I have one issue with this code, it only prints all the values to one, It doesn't seem to display any values higher than that. It seems like the if statement is never met "if output_entry.get(product_name):", and so whatever I set the else statement value to, is what all the values become

Comment: Also sorry what does the if statement check for exactly? I don't understand it fully. Thank you!