# Creating a new dictionary from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, that looks like this:

```
my_dicts = 
[{'1A': 1, '3E': 2, 'PRODUCT NAME': 'White Bread loaf large', 'Week': 1},
 {'1A': 1, '1B': 1, '1C': 1, '1D': 2, '1E': 2, '2C': 1, '3E': 2, 'PRODUCT NAME': 'Brown Bread loaf 
 large', 'Week': 1}...]
```

I want to create a new dictionary, that looks like this:

```
new_dict = 
[{'HOUSE NAME': '1A', 'White Bread Loaf Large' : 1, 'Brown Bread loaf large' : 1},
 {'HOUSE NAME': '1B', 'Brown Bread loaf large' : 1},...
 {'HOUSE NAME': '3E', 'White Bread Loaf Large' : 2, 'Brown Bread Loaf Large' : 2}]
```

Each 'HOUSE NAME' is unique.

I have a solution, that creates the new dictionary, and works with the sample list I've provided, but it does not work for my actual list (that contains 27 dictionaries)

This is the solution:

```
houses = set(['1A', '1B', '1C', '1D', '3E'])

output_list = []

for house in houses:
    output_entry = {}
    output_entry["HOUSE NAME"] = house
    for entry in my_dicts:
        if entry.get(house) and entry.get("PRODUCT NAME"):
            product_name = entry.get("PRODUCT NAME")
            if output_entry.get(product_name):
                output_entry[product_name] += 1
            else:
                output_entry[product_name] = 1

    output_list.append(output_entry)
```

The solution's last if statement doesnt seem to work, as whatever I set the 'else's condition to, is what my values are set to.

Comment: Are you sure the real list has the same product name and house in different dictionaries? I can't see any problem with the logic.

Comment: yes definitely, because the output gives me mostly the correct output, just some of the 'PRODUCT NAME' values are wrong when appended to the new list

Comment: The question says it always goes to the `else:`, so how are you getting mostly correct output?

Comment: Are you sure the product names are the same, including whitespace and capitalization?

Comment: Well what I mean are the keys are correct, but not the values, and 'PRODUCT NAME' is the key im extracting from, and yes all the houses have the same key

Comment: Unless you can provide a specific example where it's producing the wrong result, it's going to be hard to help.

Comment: Is the value of `entry.get(house)` used for anything in the result?

Comment: entry.get(house) returns the values from the keys, and just FYI I've found the if statement returns None

Comment: What I meant is you have `'1D': 2,` -- do you need to use the value 2 for anything in this script?

Comment: `if` statements aren't expressions, they don't return anything. They just execute the code in the body when the condition is true.

Comment: oh yeah that makes a lot of sense with the if statement thank you!! Yes I am creating a shopping list and the value is the quantity to be delivered. The original list comes from a csv file, is it possible to make a count from the csv and rewrite the values? (I assume you might need to know the csv to answer my question)

Comment: Of course it's possible, it's just arithmetic. The logic would be similar, so if you're having a problem with this code you may run into the same problem.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do through another method?

Comment: Anything is possible, it's just programming.

Comment: But this method seems to be fine, why are you looking to start over? Just figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
my_dicts = [{'1A': 1, '3E': 2, 
             'PRODUCT NAME': 'White Bread loaf large', 'Week': 1},
            {'1A': 1, '1B': 1, '1C': 1, '1D': 2, '1E': 2, '2C': 1, '3E': 2,
             'PRODUCT NAME': 'Brown Bread loaf large', 'Week': 1}]

merged = dict()
for d in my_dicts:
    for k,v in d.items():
        if k in ('PRODUCT NAME','Week'): continue # only process house names
        merged.setdefault(k,{'HOUSE NAME':k}).update({d['PRODUCT NAME']:v})
result = list(merged.values())

print(result)

[{'HOUSE NAME': '1A', 'White Bread loaf large': 1, 'Brown Bread loaf large': 1},
 {'HOUSE NAME': '3E', 'White Bread loaf large': 2, 'Brown Bread loaf large': 2},
 {'HOUSE NAME': '1B', 'Brown Bread loaf large': 1},
 {'HOUSE NAME': '1C', 'Brown Bread loaf large': 1},
 {'HOUSE NAME': '1D', 'Brown Bread loaf large': 2},
 {'HOUSE NAME': '1E', 'Brown Bread loaf large': 2},
 {'HOUSE NAME': '2C', 'Brown Bread loaf large': 1}]
```

*The `merged` dictionary serves as a temporary index to assemble the new list of dictionaries by updating them based on each house name.  Then the final result is obtained by ignoring the indexing par of `merged`, only taking the values (i.e. dictionaries merged by house)*